# Configure the OAuth consent screen and choose scopes using commands

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I try to understand if there is a method to configure the OAuth consent screen using gloud command shell or via script (gloud commands, bash or python)

https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent?hl=en

Manually it's natural, but I wanted to automate these operations of creating the consent screen, downloading the JSON credentials, enabling the API etc, but for the consent screen I don't know how to do it
On the consent screen there are fields to fill in and then send the application into production. Is there a way to do this via commands?

Comment: There is none you need to do it manually

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo is possible using service account with delegation ?

Comment: no there is no api for it so a service account cant help